# Firestore: Passing angularfire2 async data as Ionic 3 navParams not working

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angularfire2, google-cloud-firestore

```
cities: Observable<any>;


this.cities = this.fsProvider.collection('cities').map(cities => {
    return cities.map(city => {
      city.country = this.fsProvider.doc(`countries/${city.country_id}`);
      return city;
    });
});
```

`city` includes `country` info as `Observable` data. So if I pass `city` to another page as a `navParam`, just `this.navCtrl.push(AnotherPage, {city: city})`, I can't get country info on the `AnotherPage`.

I just added the demo here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-firestore.

Any thoughts are welcome.

Comment: My thinking is to flat the observable country to store real object.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is when you pass the `city` to `ContactPage`, the `country Observable` will not send data again. Let's see in detail. Your scenario:
**First**, you defined `cities` as an `Observable`. When the `cities` get data, it is shown in the template and you catch the `city` object in click function. Note that `city` is a **object**, not an `Observable` so you can use it directly and **synchronously**. It is why the `city.name` was shown in both pages.
**Second**, you defined `city.county` as an `Observable` then you show it in the template by `async` binding. At this step, you are **subscribing** the `Observable` and the firebase service will send you the data you want and  will never send it again unless there is any change in your database.
**Finally**, you send the `city` object to `ContactPage`. The `city.country` is still the **same Observable** and as I say above, you can not get the data unless there is any change in your database. Just edit your database and you can see the country in console log.
So, the solution is just using 2 different `Observable` in 2 pages by setting the `city.country` to the firebase `Observable` again. I guess you actually found it and comment it in `ContactPage`.
If you have any question, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Is your Countries collection setup correctly?  When I moved the

```
if (this.city) {
      this.city.country.subscribe((country) => {
        console.log(country);
      }, () => {
        console.log('finished');
      }, (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
    }
```

Into the onItemClick() event, it also never returned from the .subscribe.

*** Update ***

Remove the display of the country on HomePage and it works fine.  The problem seems to be that you can't subscribe to the Firestore observable more than once.  i.e. it doesn't re-run the query it just leaves you waiting for the next item which never comes.

Comment: One more test and uncovered the problem.  Remove the display of the country on HomePage and it works fine.  The problem seems to be that you can't subscribe to the Firestore observable more than once.  i.e. it doesn't re-run the query it just leaves you waiting for the next item which never comes.  (I'll edit my response just for future viewers.)

Comment: Correct, it's not a complete solution, but it points you to the point of failure which lets you figure out the workarounds and apparently pointed you in the right direction.  It doesn't need to be the 'correct' answer, but I'm not sure why you (or someone) down voted it.  on we go. :)